# Wanna compare 2 different array list, one by user input and another list from mongodb

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, duplicates, compare

I have been struggling in comparing two different array lists. I need quick solution. It's really haywire to me.

What my scenario is, I wanna remove selected values, if record is not exist in another document or if exist than skip that record only and remove other records.

I made a list of objectIds input by user, when user checked the checkboxes, I am getting that id and storing in an array and making a list as given below:

```
"id": ["62ff99e4306e722e7201657a",
"62ffb71d2a809d528067eeca",
"62f7ce478ac4537516bdec04",
"62cb1660b851d8bb6af08aa7",
"62cb1770b851d8bb6af08ad8",]
```

And comparing the above array with the below document brand field:

```
[
  {
    brand: [
      new ObjectId("62c95cae5db50418e6281916"),
      new ObjectId("62cb1660b851d8bb6af08aa7"),
      new ObjectId("62cb1770b851d8bb6af08ad8")
    ]
  },
  {
    brand: [
      new ObjectId("62c95cae5db50418e6281916"),
      new ObjectId("62cb1660b851d8bb6af08aa7"),
      new ObjectId("62cb1770b851d8bb6af08ad8")
    ]
  },
  {
    brand: [
      new ObjectId("62c95cae5db50418e6281916"),
      new ObjectId("62cb1660b851d8bb6af08aa7"),
      new ObjectId("62cb1770b851d8bb6af08ad8")
    ]
  }
]
```

Even if you see the second document which I am getting from mongodb has brand field which has duplicate records.

At the end what output I require is, when I click delete all button it has to delete total 3 records except below records which are matching in both arrays:

```
["62cb1660b851d8bb6af08aa7", "62cb1770b851d8bb6af08ad8"]
```

Would really appreciate if anyone solve my this issue.

Comment: Doesn't appear that the brand object is providing any useful information. Wouldn't it be okay to simply convert your second array into a flat array of arrays? That way, you can compare your first array to the array of arrays with reduce!

Comment: Actually, brand has more fields along with brand so, I just showed brand fields rather than showing all fields. If this is the right way to flat second array and use than we can go with that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved opposite solution based on my question and response of @im2wddrf. Have a loook on the opposite solution.

```
const listCatalog = await Catalog.aggregate([
 { $project: { _id: 0, brand: 1 } }, { $unwind: "$brand" },
]);
const checkCatalog = listCatalog.map(val => {
 return val.brand.toString()
});
const uniqueCatalog = _id.filter(val => {
 return checkCatalog.indexOf(val) === -1
});             

console.log(uniqueCatalog, "uniqueCatalog")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposed solution:

1. convert your first array (let's call it `asset1`) to a flat array.
2. Then take your second array (let's call it `asset2`), and convert that to a flat array of arrays (no objects).
3. Use reduce to compare the two and keep only the common ID's that can be found.

```
const asset1 = {
  "id": [
    "62ff99e4306e722e7201657a",
    "62ffb71d2a809d528067eeca",
    "62f7ce478ac4537516bdec04",
    "62cb1660b851d8bb6af08aa7",
    "62cb1770b851d8bb6af08ad8",
  ]
}


const asset2 = [
  {
    brand: [
      new ObjectId("62c95cae5db50418e6281916"),
      new ObjectId("62cb1660b851d8bb6af08aa7"),
      new ObjectId("62cb1770b851d8bb6af08ad8")
    ]
  },
  {
    brand: [
      new ObjectId("62c95cae5db50418e6281916"),
      new ObjectId("62cb1660b851d8bb6af08aa7"),
      new ObjectId("62cb1770b851d8bb6af08ad8")
    ]
  },
  {
    brand: [
      new ObjectId("62c95cae5db50418e6281916"),
      new ObjectId("62cb1660b851d8bb6af08aa7"),
      new ObjectId("62cb1770b851d8bb6af08ad8")
    ]
  }
];



// step 1: I would convert asset1 to a simple, flat array
const mod1 = [ ...asset1.id ]


// step 2: I would convert asset2 to an array of arrays, no objects
const mod2 = asset2.map(i => {
  return [ ...i.brand.map(b => b.toString()) ]
});



// now use reduce to extract only the common id's between mod1 and mod2
const result = mod2.reduce((accum, curr) => {
  return accum.filter(a => curr.includes(a));
}, mod1)


console.log(mod1);
console.log(mod2);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. What if I wanna get opposit values? Its giving me matching values. I need those values as well which are not matched in another variable as well. Would appreciate that too.

Comment: I have just posted my answer for opposite results as well. please comment on that if the way I approached is perfect or is there any other, right and short way to solve that.